# Cannot execute a postgres function - syntax error at IF

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

I'm trying to run a store  procedure/function on my database that shows all the users with giftlists < 5. I get an error "syntax error at or near IF"
I've run the SQL statements separately and it works fine.

```
--function counts the number of giftlists per user
--and put their names into a new table

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
  RETURNS TABLE(users_id users.users_id%TYPE, first_name users.first_name%TYPE, last_name      users.last_name%TYPE) AS
$func$
BEGIN

 -- if number of giftlists < 5
 IF(SELECT gift_lists.users_id, COUNT (gift_lists.gift_lists_id) as number_giftlists < 5    FROM gift_lists LEFT  JOIN users ON gift_lists.users_id =
  users.users_id GROUP BY gift_lists.users_id)
  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT v.users_id, v.first_name, v.last_name 
  FROM   my_view v;
ELSE
  RETURN QUERY
  SELECT v.users_id, v.first_name, v.last_name 
  FROM   my_view v;
END IF;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Comment: Just leave it out? (the IF and the ELSE block contain the same query)

Comment: Your `if` doesn't make sense.  It has a `group by`, suggesting that it will return multiple rows, but it is in a context where only a scalar subquery can be used.

Comment: `IF ... THEN ... ELSE ... END IF;`  <- you are missing `THEN`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `IF` at the top level in standard SQL, or in PostgreSQL's SQL dialect.

[Use `CASE .. WHEN ... THEN ... END`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html) instead, or use the PL/PgSQL language. PL/PgSQL allows you to use `IF` statements.

Separately, this:

```
 COUNT (gift_lists.gift_lists_id) as number_giftlists < 5
```

makes no sense. I think you mean:

```
SELECT
  gift_lists.users_id,
  COUNT (gift_lists.gift_lists_id) as number_giftlists
FROM gift_lists 
  LEFT  JOIN users ON gift_lists.users_id = users.users_id 
GROUP BY gift_lists.users_id
HAVING COUNT (gift_lists.gift_lists_id) < 5
```